# Which one is the latest stable version of cordova?

Tags: cordova

I have installed cordova referring this tutorial https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

And it installed cordova 5.1.1 in my machine which is latest. I want to know is this a stable version of cordova? And if it is not can you suggest me the stable latest version of cordova. I am new to cordova and I have to start client app development and i do not want to get stuck in between.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `Cordova 5.1.1` is a stable release and working perfectly with Android and IOS with our app. Also see [this](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/10/tools-release.html) link.

Also your documentation points to the guide for `4.0.0`, if you use `5.1.1` you are better off reading and using documentation for `5.1.1`, see [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) link.

Comment: i saw the link shared by you. Do you know any previous version of cordova which was stable and most used in industry for app development. As 5.1.1 is newer, released on 10th Jun, so i am not sure it is stable or not.

Comment: 5.1.1 is the last version of CLI and cordova tools. the platforms as well as plugins versions are different. for example platform android is currently on 4.1.0 https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/07/21/cordova-android-4.1.0.html and for plugins: https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/22/plugins-release.html